# Set a boolean to true/false by selecting 2 IDs in arrays

Tags: javascript

EDIT: one part of my function was missing.

It's my first time posting here so let me know if I'm doing it wrong.

Here is my problem:

My data is like this:

```
const lists = [
    {
      idl: 'todo-0',
      namel: 'Example 1',
      tasks: [{ taskName: 'task', completedTask: true, taskId: "Un" },{ taskName: 'task2', completedTask: true, taskId: "Deux" },{ taskName: 'task3', completedTask: true, taskId: "Trois" }]
    },
     {
      idl: 'todo-1',
      namel: 'Example 2',
      tasks: [{ taskName: 'task', completedTask: true, taskId: "Un" },{ taskName: 'task2', completedTask: true, taskId: "Deux" },{ taskName: 'task3', completedTask: true, taskId: "Trois" }]
    }]
```

I tried a lot of thing and VScode get angry because of my synthax. I can aim the 2 array I want with this function but it remove the keys of tasks :<

```
const toggleTask = (listId: string, taskId: string) => {
    const listIndex = lists.findIndex((list)=>list.idl === listId);
  const list = lists[listIndex]
  const newList = {
    ...list,
    tasks: list.tasks.map((task)=> {if (taskId=== task.taskId){return task.completedTask === true} } )
  }

  const newLists = [
    ...lists.slice(0,listIndex),
    newList,
    ...lists.slice(listIndex + 1),
  ]
  console.log('newLists2', newLists)

}
```

What I would like is for example:

toggleTask("todo-1", "Un")

exepected output:

```
[
    {
      idl: 'todo-0',
      namel: 'Example 1',
      tasks: [{ taskName: 'task', completedTask: true, taskId: "Un" },{ taskName: 'task2', completedTask: true, taskId: "Deux" },{ taskName: 'task3', completedTask: true, taskId: "Trois" }]
    },
     {
      idl: 'todo-1',
      namel: 'Example 2',
      tasks: [{ taskName: 'task', completedTask: false, taskId: "Un" },{ taskName: 'task2', completedTask: true, taskId: "Deux" },{ taskName: 'task3', completedTask: true, taskId: "Trois" }]
    }]
```

Comment: You need to make it clear specifically what you are trying to achieve and what is not working. What is your input? What is your function? What did you expect the output to be> What is the actual output? Is there any error message? Please edit your question to make this clear so others can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it helps

```
const toggleTask = (listId, taskId) => {
  const newLists = lists.map(listItem => {
    if(listItem.idl === listId){
      listItem.tasks.map(task => {
        if(task.taskId === taskId) {
          task.completedTask = !task.completedTask;
        }
        return task;
      });
    }
    return listItem;
  });
  console.log(newLists);
};
```

Comment: Hi ! I haven't tried your code, but it seems that `task.completedTask = task.taskId === taskId ? true : false;` may be : `task.completedTask = task.taskId === taskId;` :)

Comment: Ohh yeah. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works well and it helps me to build other function.

But my linter bully me because of this: task.completedTask = !task.completedTask;

It doesn't like when we change a variable?